# "How is USA" vs "How is the USA"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, articles, definite-articles

One of my colleagues has been to the USA recently, and I want to ask him how the country is. Which of the below is grammatically correct?

> 1. How is USA?

or

> 2. How is the USA?

Is "the" actually required in the above context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Using the definite article before a country/state name](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)* Also see *[Use of definite article before phrases like Heathrow Airport](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34704)*

Comment: Yes, you need to say How is the USA?

Answer (score 3):

The correct grammatical way to say it would be

> How is the USA?

because USA stands for **U**nited **S**tates of **A**merica. It would be incorrect to say

> How is USA?

because this means

> How is United States of America?

It is missing a definite article (***the***), since there is only one USA.

So, to answer your question, **yes**, you would need the "***the***".

Comment: The article is required because *states* is a countable noun, not because there is only one USA. You wouldn't ask *how is the Russia?* although you could ask *how is the Russian Federation*?

Comment: @choster  Then wouldn't  you say how are the USA, as there are fifty of the states?.

Comment: @davidlol You *could* say that, and it was more common to do so in the 19th century, but the country is a single entity composed of multiple states, and it is conventional to speak of it as a whole, no different from *the Philippines is*, *the United Arab Emirates is*, and so forth.

Comment: I'm really not convinced by this argument. Once the abbreviation becomes a standalone idiom to the point no one really expands it mentally anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it would be The United States of America in the same way that Buckeyes fans talk about The Ohio State University. I believe 'The' implies a certain federation between States that value their independence and the ability to make and uphold their own laws; regarding the use of the indicative preposition 'the', perhaps the truth of the matter is that it may be subjective to age... I would say yes, personally; as stated above, I appreciate the use of the properly idenifying preposition and all it implies. With that said, if you are a millennial, and elect to use the term 'America' outside of the usual context and conjecture, then screw it... 'Merca!

Comment: article. Excuse me, you are right, it is not a preposition. It's the indicative article.