# "Green Park" or "The Green Park"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why there is “the” before some names but not others](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/why-there-is-the-before-some-names-but-not-others)

When do you use definite article with names of places?

I have gathered from [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Park) that it is correct to say "The Green Park is a park ..." and "... a fireworks celebration held in Green Park". What are the differences between these sentences? Why the use of *the* in the former situation but not the latter?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Use of definite article before phrases like Heathrow Airport, Hyde Park, Waterloo Station, Edgware Road and Parliament Square](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/34704/8019) and [Definite article with proper nouns, titles followed by a common noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2327/8019)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of common usage rather than correctness. The [official website](http://www.royalparks.org.uk/parks/green-park/) of *(The) Green Park* uses both, but I would tend to use *Green Park* in speech and most writing. The Underground station is also called *Green Park*.

By contrast, I would almost always use the article *the* when referring to *The Royal Mile* in Edinburgh.

A special case would be when using a possessive, when I would drop the *the*: for instance, one might talk of Edinburgh's *Royal Mile*, or London's *Green Park*.

Comment: The question is from an English assignment where I am asked to add the definite article where it needs to be. The phrase is "We decided to take a stroll in () Green Park". Even though english is my second language, I feel like it should be "in Green Park" and not "in the Green Park", but I cannot explain why.

Even if it is only common usage, what would be the descriptive explanation of the usage?

Comment: *Green Park* is an acceptable noun-phrase, just like *Hyde Park*. You are correct that it should not be *in the Green Park* because here *Green* cannot be legitimately split from *Park*. On the other hand, if the question spoke of *green park* rather than *Green Park*, *green* would be an adjective, and could be split from *park*. The use of *the* would then serve to distinguish *the green park* from *the brown park*, *the yellow park*, etc.