# Definite article when referring to named works

Tags: definite-articles

If I've watched a named film, let's say "Ice Age".

Is it incorrect to say:

> "I was watching Ice Age film"

Without a definite article?

As opposed to:

> "I was watching the Ice Age film".

If you have to include "the" - why is that?

Comment: I was watching *Ice Age*.  I was watching the film "Ice Age".

Comment: The examples in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/definite-article-with-proper-nouns-titles-followed-by-a-common-noun) on definite articles with proper nouns show the contrast.  Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, 'Ice Age' acts as an adjective and the impression is that you are watching film footage that was brought back from the Ice Age. In the second instance, it seems that the film is about the Ice Age but not clear which film - having used 'the' we are talking about an Ice age film that is probably known at the time of watching but lacks enough context to determine if the film is named like this. If the film was released recently and it is well known this option is better.
In order to sound specific to the feature film, I propose:

"I was watching Ice Age, the film."
or just
"I was watching Ice Age"

I hope this helps.